# JavaFX-приложение с графическим интерфейсом для работы с графиками функций. Реализация технологии drag and drop и получение координат точек

Tags: javafx, drag-n-drop

Учусь.Выполняю учебный проект по созданию приложения на Java с использованием графической библиотеки JavaFX,программы Scene Builder.Программа имеет поля для ввода функции, ввода диапазона аргументов, ввода количества точек, необходимых для построения графика функции. В приложении используется библиотека Javaluator (это библиотека для расчета "инфиксных выражений" на вход в метод поступают значения аргумента, на выходе значения функции. Данные записываются в ArrayList в котором список из массивов каждый массив имеет 3 параметра в следующей последовательности: координата х, координата у, третий параметр NULL, библиотека доступна в репозитории maven). Строится график функции. После этого необходимо захватить любую точку (из серии точек) и перетянуть эту точку, изменив, тем самым, график функции. При этом в поле введенной функции должна измениться введенная функция. Проблема с реализацией drag and drop перетягиваю точку, бросаю, график начинает "гулять",изменяется масштаб осей, хотя перетягивал точку буквально на пару сантиметров и проблема с обновлением данных в коллекции.
Для вывода измененной функции используется метод в классе "Полиномиальная регрессия", создается объект данного класса, к объекту применяется метод, на вход в метод поступают два массива со значениями аргумента и значениями функции, количество членов полинома. В поле введенной функции отображается полином (с ним нет проблем работает, выводит результат).

```
XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
series.setName(function);
ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
series.getData();
DoubleEvaluator eval = new DoubleEvaluator();
Double temp;
StaticVariableSet<Double> variables = new StaticVariableSet<>();
for (double x = minX; x <= maxX; x += (maxX - minX) / numberOfPoints) {
    variables.set("x", x);
    variables.set("X", x);
    temp = eval.evaluate(function, variables);
    //Проверяем каждое значение функции на исключение, если функция бесконечна, то об этом будет выведена информация
    if (temp.isInfinite())
        throw new RuntimeException("Бесконечное значение функции");
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, temp));
    list.add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, temp));
}
variables.set("x", maxX);
variables.set("X", maxX);
temp = eval.evaluate(function, variables);
//Проверяем последнее значение функции на исключение, если функция бесконечна, то об этом будет выведена информация
if (temp.isInfinite())
    throw new RuntimeException("Бесконечное значение функции");
//Добавляем последнюю точку в серии
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(maxX, temp));
list.add(new XYChart.Data<>(maxX, temp));
//Строим оси координат и график
lineChart.getData().add(series);
//Создаем два массива xValues и yValues, в которые будут записаны координаты по осям x и y, соответственно.
//Оба массива являются аргументами для метода polynomialRegression
double[] xValues = new double[numberOfPoints];
double[] yValues = new double[numberOfPoints];
//При помощи цикла "foreach"(обход по коллекции), создаем объекты - узлы (для каждой точки в серии). Назначаем обработчик события мыши для каждой точки.
Point2D point = new Point2D(0,0);


for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data : series.getData()) {

    Node node = data.getNode();
    node.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    node.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        //
        point.xValue = e.getX();
        point.yValue = e.getY();
        data.setXValue(point.xValue);
        data.setYValue(point.yValue);
        startX = point.xValue;
        startY = point.yValue;
        node.localToParent(startX, startY);
        System.out.println("начальная координата Х точки "+startX+","+"начальная координата Y точки "+startY);
    });
    node.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        System.out.println("Происходит перетаскивание узла.");
    });
    node.setOnMouseDragReleased(e -> {
        point.xValue = e.getX();
        point.yValue = e.getY();
        data.setXValue(point.xValue);
        data.setYValue(point.yValue);
        finishX = point.xValue;
        finishY = point.yValue;
        System.out.println("Конечная координата Х точки "+startX+","+"Конечная координата Y точки "+startY);
    });
}
//list.set();
//list.set(list.indexOf(e.getY()), data );


for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
    xValues[i] = (double) (list.get(i).getXValue());
    yValues[i] = (double) (list.get(i).getYValue());
}
PolynomialRegression regression = new PolynomialRegression(xValues, yValues, 6, "x");
equation.setText(regression.toString());
```